# Table names, and loop to describe

Tags: sql, oracle, describe

Working in Oracle 10g.  Easy way to list all tables names (select table_name from dba_tables where owner = 'me')
But now that I have the table names, is there an easy way to loop through them and do a 'describe' on each one in sequence?

Comment: Easier to do "select table_name from user_tables;" than to query dba_tables with a where clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [describe query with oracle (.Net Connector)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867731/describe-query-with-oracle-net-connector)

Answer (score 2):

You could query against DBA_TAB_COLUMNS (or USER_TAB_COLUMNS).

Nicolas.

Comment: And make sure to sort them appropriately (on COLUMN_ID), otherwise the columns will not look like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do a describe from within PL/SQL. I just tried using `execute immediate 'describe some_table'`, that doesn't work either. Your next choice would be to query DBA_TAB_COLUMNS, or create a new file with all your describe statements (using dbms_output from pl/sql and spool to create the file) and then execute that file. Maybe like this:

```
spool temp_file.sql
BEGIN
    /*or you could have a loop here with as many put_lines as you need, it will all end up in the new script file.*/
    dbms_output.put_line('describe some_table');
END;
/
spool off
@temp_file.sql
/*I have not actually tried running this code, beware syntax errors!*/
```

Comment: You can't do it from PL/SQL -- you are right.  That's because "describe", like "set", "copy", and some other commands, is actually a SQLPlus command, not a SQL statement.  So outside of that environment, you cannot execute it.  You can tell because it requires no terminal semi-colon to execute.  SQL statements, whether they are DML or DDL, require semi-colons or some terminating character other than [Enter] to send to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in PL/SQL using [DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_metada.htm#i1015856), e.g. (example taken from docs):

```
SET LONG 2000000
SET PAGESIZE 0
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','EMP','SCOTT') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. login with the user and then run the following commands, first file will contain the describe commands and the second file will be the desired file containing all the descriptions of all tables for logged in user

   ```
   spool desctables.sql
   select 'describe '||table_name||';' from user_tables;
   spool off
   spool alltables.txt
   @desctables.sql
   spool off
   ```

Comment: this worked great for me, I did have a couple issues in that first the command line was too long (I had 500 tables) so I broke it into batches of 100, next I had to remove the "command>" at the top and bottom, finally I had to remove the "< " and " >" that wrapped each describe statement (I probably should have turned it off).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend querying dba_tab_columns, as N. Gasparotto suggested, but if you really want describe output then create a file mulit-describe.sql with the following:

```
set pagesize 0
set termout off
set feedback off
set verify off

spool mdtmp.sql
select 'describe ' || owner || '.' || table_name
from dba_tables
where OWNER = upper('&1')
/

spool off
set termout on
@mdtmp.sql
```

Within SQL*PLUS run by:

```
@multi-describe ME
```